# How to find y value in line-and-dots plot?

Tags: r

I have this line-and-dots plot:

```
#generate fake data
xLab <- seq(0, 50, by=5);
yLab <- c(0, sort(runif(10, 0, 1)));

#this value is fixed
fixedVal <- 27.3

#new window
dev.new();

#generate the plot
paste0(plot(xLab, yLab, col=rgb(50/255, 205/255, 50/255, 1), type="o", lwd=3, 
    main="a line-and-dots plot", xlab="some values", ylab="a percentage",
    pch=20, xlim=c(0, 50), ylim=c(0, 1), xaxt="n", cex.lab=1.5, cex.axis=1.5, 
    cex.main=1.5, cex.sub=1.5));

#set axis
axis(side = 1, at=c(seq(min(xLab), max(xLab), by=5)))

#plot line
abline(v=fixedVal, col="firebrick", lwd=3, lty=1);
```

now, I would like to find the y coordinate of the intersection point between the green and the red lines.

Can I achieve the goal without the need of a regression line? Is there a simple way of getting the coordinates of that unknown point?

Comment: hmm, maybe check out the locator function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34248347/r-locate-intersection-of-two-curves ? Otherwise you really have to work out the gradient between those two points

Comment: Just type `locator(1)` while the graph is displayed and click on the point.

Comment: @StupidWolf I knew somebody already asked something similar. I'll go through that answer you suggested

Comment: @JohnColeman it work but I need that exact point, which is not easy to get by pointing a mouse! I'll look into the other aswer suggested above

Comment: The graph is piece-wise linear, just find the piece which contains `fixedVal` and do the algebra. Regression is not really relevant.

Comment: Ok i posted something below.. might be a quick fix.. note it only works in your piecewise case

Comment: @JohnColeman, ok following the lead!

Comment: @StupidWolf I was doing something similar but you were faster so...thank you!

Comment: I started to do the algebra but then remembered the magic word "interpolation" and then guessed correctly that base R had to have linear interpolation built in. A quick Google search brought me to `approx`, which I had never used before.

Comment: yeah @JohnColeman, i think it's a good solution..

Comment: @StupidWolf it is still good to go through the details sometimes, just to verify what is happening. Sometimes subtle differences in definitions can yield different results.

Comment: You're welcome! I learned something new today, thanks to both you and @JohnColeman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `approxfun` to do the interpolation:

```
> approxfun(xLab,yLab)(fixedVal)
[1] 0.3924427
```

Alternatively, just use `approx`:

```
> approx(xLab,yLab,fixedVal)
$x
[1] 27.3

$y
[1] 0.3924427
```

Comment: why is there a difference between the results you get and the results from the other answer? I suppose that deriving the linear interpolation should give the same values.

Comment: No difference -- you didn't use `set.seed` so different runs produce something different. That actually threw me at first, since I wondered why `approx` and `approxfun` gave different answers, until I realized they didn't, when fed the same data.

Comment: This is a really helpful answer. I didn't realize before that `approxfun` returned a function - had to look for more detail on why that second set of parentheses works.

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix like @JohnColeman said:

```
# find the two points flanking your value
idx <- findInterval(fixedVal,xLab)
# calculate the deltas
y_delta <- diff(yLab[idx:(idx+1)])
x_delta <- diff(xLab[idx:(idx+1)])

# interpolate... 
ycut = (y_delta/x_delta) * (fixedVal-xLab[idx]) + yLab[idx]
ycut
[1] 0.4046399
```

So we try it on the plot..

```
paste0(plot(xLab, yLab, col=rgb(50/255, 205/255, 50/255, 1), type="o", lwd=3, 
    main="a line-and-dots plot", xlab="some values", ylab="a percentage",
    pch=20, xlim=c(0, 50), ylim=c(0, 1), xaxt="n", cex.lab=1.5, cex.axis=1.5, 
    cex.main=1.5, cex.sub=1.5));

#set axis
axis(side = 1, at=c(seq(min(xLab), max(xLab), by=5)))

#plot line
abline(v=fixedVal, col="firebrick", lwd=3, lty=1);
abline(h=ycut, col="lightblue", lwd=3, lty=1);
```

[image]